# Implement a destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class: `A` and I wrote the destructor.

now I have a class `B`:

```
class B {
    A* a;
  public:
    B() {
      a = new A[10];
    }

    ~B() {

    }

};
```

I want to implement the destructor of B.

I think something like:

```
~B() {
  delete[] a;
}
```

but I got an error.

maybe I have to do the next line?

```
delete a;
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: `delete[] a;` is correct. What is the error you get?

Comment: probably you omitted some relevant code?

Comment: I will check it again as soon as it possible.. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what error you got, but the following compiles without errors:

```
class A {};

class B {
    A* a;
  public:
    B() {
      a = new A[10];
    }

    ~B() {
      delete[] a;
    }
};
```

Note that this is incomplete in that it violates the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). `B::a` should either be a suitable smart pointer, or the class needs to implement a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator (or [disable both](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable)). An even better option is to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of the raw pointer.

Comment: ... or it should be an appropriate container class from the standard library.

Comment: @moooeeeep: Good point, thanks. I've updated the answer to include this.